# Inserting <string, function pointer> into map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, function-pointers, typedef

I'm having trouble with inserting some value_pairs into a map. Here's the basic idea.

```
// private
typedef Foo* (*Bar)( const std::string &x, int y );
typedef std::map<std::string, Bar> myMap;

template<class T>
Foo* DoThing( const std::string &x, int y ) {
  return new T( x, y );
}

myMap m_map;

// some map insertion code
m_map.insert( myMap::value_type( "blah", &DoThing<SomeType> ));
m_map.insert( myMap::value_type( "blech", &DoThing<OtherType> ));
```

This would give a compiler error saying `no matching function call to std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Foo* (*)(const std::string&, int)>::pair(const char [5], <unresolved overloaded function type>)` Not sure what I'm doing wrong syntactically, or why I'm getting the `unresolved overloaded function type`. My best guess is that it doesn't know that `DoThing` returns a `Foo*`.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm using g++. Hmm.. Made the template function a bit more specific.

Comment: Just to be sure, `DoThing<T>` is a global function and not a member of  any class, right?  If it's inside a class, it needs to be a static member function.

Comment: @Ben Doh! That was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Ben, write that as a short answer and you will get credit for it and @ggg will be able to accept an answer.

Comment: @David: I had a slight advantage from answering (fixing the typedef) on his previous question, in which the out-of-line definition of DoThing was provided, and it was clearly a class member (but without the declaration there was still no indication of whether or not it was static).

Comment: On a side note, I'd recommend making the value a `std::function` object instead of a function pointer as it gives you more flexibility on what in can hold.

Answer (score 5):

Comment converted to answer:

Just to be sure, `DoThing<T>` is a global function and not a member of any class, right? If it's inside a class, it needs to be a static member function.

Also, if you take the address of a member function, some compilers insist on qualifying it with the class name, e.g. `&MyClass::DoThing<T>`.  Again, if it is a static member function, you get an ordinary function pointer.  If a non-static member function, you get a pointer-to-member and the `this` pointer must be supplied at the call site.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a ',' before the second &.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it doesn't know how to convert the "blah" and "blech" to std::strings. If you construct these explicitly I think it should work.

Comment: That could certainly have been one of the problems, but didn't solve it.